# Use generic by adding another type to interface in JSX

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo, typescript-generics

I came across an error that I don't know how to solve.

I have a generic component in React Native that takes a `T` value extending `unknow`.

However, inside this type `T` I'm sure I'll have a type called "name".

The question is...is there any way to use the generic type and, in addition, put the name as the default of `T`?

My code is this...

```
type GridProps<T> = {
  data: T[];
};

export function Grid<T extends unknown>({ data }: GridProps<T>) {
  const { sizes } = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <GridHeader>
        <Text content={`Encontrados ${data.length} items.`} color="gray-400" />
      </GridHeader>
      <FlashList
        numColumns={2}
        data={data}
        estimatedItemSize={data.length}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
          <GridItem
            style={
              index % 2 === 0
                ? { marginRight: sizes[2] }
                : { marginLeft: sizes[2] }
            }
          >
            <Text content={item.name} />
          </GridItem>
        )}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to extend `unknown`. It is equivalent to just provide nothing.

You can just extend `T` with the type that should always be present for `T`.

```js
Grid<T extends { name: string }>
```